# Two different voltages from a single transformer without a common ground

Tags: transformer, ground, bridge-rectifier

I have a transformer with four taps; 8, 16 and 24 V and I want to have a switchable and an stable 24 V from this transformer.

I've asked [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/473216/getting-several-voltages-from-a-single-transformer) before and you told me that I can't have a common ground between two bridges.

Can I do it like the diagram below without having a common ground?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faRyED.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I need that stable 24 V for the relays supply.

Comment: I guess so. In this arrangement, you don't have anything in common between the two bridge rectifiers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it’s fine.

Of course you would need flyback diodes across the relay coils and probably a driver circuit to get enough coil current reliably.